# Using one APNS push service certificate for two different AWS pinpoint instances

Tags: apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I have two AWS pinpoints. Each for different environment one for production, and one for development. We need separate pinpoints as we need also to test new features such as new type push notification or other custom metrics on development before pushing it to production.

I am using one APNS push certificate for both (the certificate has production and sandbox capability). I understand that Apple stated one certificate can be used only for one app. And I only use one app for it. But as mentioned above, I use two environments.
My question is will there be any problem with this? Any best practice for this situation? Should I use different certificate for different pinpoint?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounter same problem. THe cause is just permission issue. It has nothing to do with using same certificate. for different environments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).